# Matplotlib time scaled line graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

```
    # get data from database
    count = 0
    times = []

    async for x1 in self.client.totalInfections.find({}, {'time'}):
        count += 1
        x2 = x1['time']
        times.append(x2)

    # you're gonna need to make a new list for that, where the index is determined by the hour in the date
    # you just always add to the last element of your new list unless the previous item in your times list had a different hour in which case append to the new list instead

    newNumbers = []
    previousX = None
    hours = {}
    if previousX is None:
        previousX = times[0]

    for x in times:
        try:
            if x.hour == previousX.hour:
                hours[x.hour].append(x.hour)
            else:
                previousX = x
        except KeyError:
            hours[x.hour] = [x.hour]
    print(hours)
    # make up some data
    x = times  # time
    y = hours  # amount to plot

    ax = plt.subplot()

    # set the basic properties
    ax.set_xlabel('Time of infection')
    ax.set_ylabel('Infections')
    ax.set_title('Daily infections')

    # plot
    plt.plot(x, y)
    # beautify the x-labels
    # plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # diagonal x lables
    plt.savefig('F:\Discord Pandemic/test.png')

    file = discord.File("F:\Discord Pandemic/test.png", filename="test.png")
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://test.png")
    await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

---

```
Ignoring exception in command infections:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Discord Pandemic\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Discord Pandemic\cogs\infections.py", line 59, in infections
    x = times.hour  # time
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

---

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Discord Pandemic\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "F:\Discord Pandemic\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "F:\Discord Pandemic\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Hey guys, I'm not sure if anybody could help me here, I'm trying to plot a graph which resembles something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3CFR.png)

[image]

However, I'm getting an error as seen above, which im unsure how to fix. Any help would be a very happy inducing thing to do :)

I have tried many different things, no of which resulted in a graph which did not meet my requirements.

Comment: The error looks like to be ```x = times.hour```. As the error indicates, ```time``` is a list. Defined as so, by you, in the beginning of the code. What were you trying to achieve with this line of code?

Comment: @fdireito Im trying to plot all the data in my `hours` list onto my graph so instead of it looking like this: https://gyazo.com/59ef037588e6100a319e68b8d9223c1b 

it will look like this: https://gyazo.com/bafe57b97598dd1d49ca9cf63bc004c0

Comment: Maybe ```x = [i.hour for i in times]```, instead of ```x = times.hour```

Comment: ```Command raised an exception: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5143,) and (1,)
```

Got a similar error unfortunetly!

Comment: It doesn't look like the same error. When you ```print(hours)```, does it look like what you wanted?

Comment: @fdireito Yes, hours is how i want it. I just cannot seem to get it to display on my graph.

Comment: Ok, so x is an array with 5143 length, while the hours should be a dictionary. Could you please show the result of print(hours) (or at least its beginning, if it is too big)?